# Prove $E(V(XY|X+Y)) = 0$.

Tags: probability

> Let $X,Y$, two Bernoulli random variables with parameter $0 < p < 1$.  Prove $E(V(XY|X+Y)) = 0$.

I know there's an easy way, but I wish to prove it using the following identity:

$$V(XY) = E(V(XY|X+Y)) + V(E(XY|X+Y))$$

Since $(XY)$ is also a Bernoulli  $$V(XY) = E((XY)^2) - E(XY)^2 = E(XY) - E(XY)^2 = p^2 - p^4$$

$$V(E(XY|X+Y)) = V(E(XY)) = V(p^2) = 0$$

Where is my mistake? I think the evaluation of $Var(XY)$ is wrong.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $XY$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable for $Z=X+Y$ since $$XY=\tfrac12Z(Z-1),$$ hence $$V(XY\mid Z)=0\ \text{almost surely}.$$

Comment: How does the accepted answer answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't actually. I don't know why I accepted it